# Pass DataGridViewCell by Reference

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to pass a DataGridViewCell to a method which changes the cell type depending on certain conditions, e.g.

```
var valueCell = currentRow.Cells["ValueColumn2"];
PopulateValueCell(attribute, attributeValue, valueCell);
```

but it appears to pass the cell by value and hence not update the cell in my grid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `currentRow.Cells["ValueColumn2"];` is a `DataGridViewCell`. You can pass its reference and set its `.Value` property to anything compatible with its `ValueType`.

Comment: To clarify, in `PopulateValueCell()`, I want to set valueCell to a descendent of DataGridViewCell, e.g. DataGridViewComboBoxCell. I have this working fine if I don't pass the cell into a different method.

Comment: It's the same thing. What matters is if the ComboBox values are filled by a DataSource or not. Add to your question all the details needed to understand in what context your code is not performing as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following points:

- When you pass a an object by value, you cannot change it's reference. You can just change it's properties. So to change the reference of the object you need to pass it by `ref`.
- In the other hand, `Cells[index]` is an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and you cannot pass it by [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

To replace the member of the collection at a specific index, you need to pass the collection and the index and assign new value to the collection at specified index.

So you can change your code to pass those information (cells collection of the specific row and the column index) or any other information which helps you to get `Cells[index]`.

For example, the following code, passes [`DataGridViewCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) as parameter, but extracts the owning collection and the cell index and then changes the cell:

```
void ChangeCellType(DataGridViewCell c)
{
    var index = c.OwningColumn.Index;
    var cells = c.OwningRow.Cells;

    var newCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    newCell.ValueType = typeof(bool);
    newCell.Value = true;

    cells[index] = newCell;
}
```

> Please note: The answer doesn't encourage you to use above method, because I don't
>   have any idea about the use case which you are trying to implement.
>   But it tries to describe the problem and shows how you can change your
>   code to make it working.

Comment: Cool! No problem :)